# How to run console application from Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application

I have a windows service, written in c# and I need to run a console application from it.
Console application also written in c#.

Console application is running fine when it is run not from windows service. When it is ran from ws it doesn`t do anything it should and as it should work for 10-20 seconds I see in debug code is executed at once.

I`m starting my console app with the following code:

```
proc.Start(fullPathToConsole, args);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

the path to console is right and when I`m trying to run it from the cmd or just in explorer (without args) it works fine. But after running with the service I see no effect.

I already tried to go to service properties and give it access to desktop and run under both system and my user (also specified in service properties). All remains the same.

ADDITION: I know service do not have ui and I don't want one. I want service to run console application. No need to get any data from it or use this console like ui, just run it to do it`s job.

UPDATE I: discovered, that running calc or any other windows app is easy. But still can`t run cmd or any console app. Actually I need to run it on XP SP2 and Windows 2003 Server. So do not need to interact with Vista in anyway.

Would be glad to any comments!

Comment: What's the purpose of the console window in relation to this application?  Perhaps if we had an idea of the concept of the application we could provide a more appropriate solution.

Comment: actually it doesn`t matter. The problem is that I can`t launch it. If you know how to launch console with the service - please post the code. The reasons why I need that are too long. I know that when you need one app to run other and this other does something else it looks like arch smell, but believe me, I have reasons to need this :-)

Comment: Your reasons to need it are irrelevant.  Really.  Microsoft has always frowned on services interacting with the desktop, but ever since the shatter attack was invented, they've decided to deprecate the ability and remove it completely.  You will need to figure out a different solution.

Comment: What is the console application? Is it waiting for some IO? If so, it may be blocked until your service provides this IO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Starting from Windows Vista, a service cannot interact with the desktop. You will not be able to see any windows or console windows that are started from a service. See this [MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/f8f91e8f-5954-43a7-8bc4-80ed2ff1e3b1).

On other OS, there is an option that is available in the service option called "Allow Service to interact with desktop". Technically, you should program for the future and should follow the Vista guideline even if you don't use it on Vista.

If you still want to run an application that never interact with the desktop, try specifying the process to not use the shell.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\myprogram.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.ErrorDialog = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process process = Process.Start(info);
```

See if this does the trick.

First you inform Windows that the program won't use the shell (which is inaccessible in Vista to service).

Secondly, you redirect all consoles interaction to internal stream (see `process.StandardInput` and `process.StandardOutput`.

Comment: I don`t need to see anything. All I need - launch the console app, and it will do the job. I know that service do not have ui etc. The question is about how to launch console from service app.

Comment: Then don't call it a console app. A console app have a UI, which is the console. Try changing it to a Windows Application, but that don't show anything.

Comment: I have 2 apps: service and console app. Console app does it job and has no interaction with user. So I wrote that I don`t need any ui for service or for console to interact with the user, I need to launch console app to do it`s job and need to do it from my service. What did I say wrong?

Comment: A console application as configured in Visual Studio does have a UI: The Console itself. This might be why you are unable to start it with the Windows Service. Even if and since you never interact with the user, you do not need that application to be a Console application.

Comment: Ok let`s treat it like a special case and get back to the question: how can I launch console with service? I know that if I can switch it all with winform I should write winform app or use only service. But I need to launch console from service :-(

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant:  Your comment is not strictly true.  Windows services *can* interact with the desktop under Windows XP, although the feature has essentially been removed from Vista.  That notwithstanding, this still doesn't address Yaroslav's question.

Comment: I updated the answer to make the distinction between the Vista and XP behavior.

Comment: Updated the question. Still need the answer.

Comment: Will update this question in a few days. Would like to thank Pierre-Alain Vigeant for his help. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Usually, I create a WinForm application with a hidden form and launch it from the service. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>I've done this before successfully - I have some code at home.  When I get home tonight, I'll update this answer with the working code of a service launching a console app.</strike>

I thought I'd try this from scratch.  Here's some code I wrote that launches a console app.  I installed it as a service and ran it and it worked properly: cmd.exe launches (as seen in Task Manager) and lives for 10 seconds until I send it the exit command.  I hope this helps your situation as it does work properly as expected here.

```
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe");
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
        //// do some other things while you wait...
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // simulate doing other things...
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit"); // tell console to exit
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.WaitForExit(120000); // give 2 minutes for process to finish
            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill(); // took too long, kill it off
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows Services do not have UIs. You can redirect the output from a console app to your service with the code shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040706/).

Comment: I don`t need to have a UI or redirect an output. I need to launch a console app and let it do the job. I don`t need any ui, so it`s not the way out.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SystemControl
{
    class Services
    {
        static string strPath = @"D:\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strServiceName = "WindowsService1";
            CreateFolderStructure(strPath);
            string svcPath = @"D:\Applications\MSC\Agent\bin\WindowsService1.exe";
            if (!IsInstalled(strServiceName))
            {
                InstallAndStart(strServiceName, strServiceName, svcPath + " -k runservice");                
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(strServiceName + " already installed. Do you want to Uninstalled the Service.Y/N.?");
                string strKey = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strKey) && (strKey.StartsWith("y")|| strKey.StartsWith("Y")))
                {
                    StopService(strServiceName);
                    Uninstall(strServiceName);
                    ServiceLogs(strServiceName + " Uninstalled.!", strPath);
                    Console.Write(strServiceName + " Uninstalled.!");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }

        #region "Environment Variables"
        public static string GetEnvironment(string name, bool ExpandVariables = true)
        {
            if (ExpandVariables)
            {
                return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
            }
            else
            {
                return (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\").GetValue(name, "", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
            }
        }

        public static void SetEnvironment(string name, string value)
        {
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region "ServiceCalls Native"
        public static ServiceController[] List { get { return ServiceController.GetServices(); } }

        public static void Start(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }

        public static void Stop(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ...
            }
        }

        public static void Restart(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

                // count the rest of the timeout
                int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
                timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ...
            }
        }

        public static bool IsInstalled(string serviceName)
        {
            // get list of Windows services
            ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

            // try to find service name
            foreach (ServiceController service in services)
            {
                if (service.ServiceName == serviceName)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region "ServiceCalls API"
        private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
        private const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

        [Flags]
        public enum ServiceManagerRights
        {
            Connect = 0x0001,
            CreateService = 0x0002,
            EnumerateService = 0x0004,
            Lock = 0x0008,
            QueryLockStatus = 0x0010,
            ModifyBootConfig = 0x0020,
            StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
            AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | Connect | CreateService |
            EnumerateService | Lock | QueryLockStatus | ModifyBootConfig)
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum ServiceRights
        {
            QueryConfig = 0x1,
            ChangeConfig = 0x2,
            QueryStatus = 0x4,
            EnumerateDependants = 0x8,
            Start = 0x10,
            Stop = 0x20,
            PauseContinue = 0x40,
            Interrogate = 0x80,
            UserDefinedControl = 0x100,
            Delete = 0x00010000,
            StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
            AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | QueryConfig | ChangeConfig |
            QueryStatus | EnumerateDependants | Start | Stop | PauseContinue |
            Interrogate | UserDefinedControl)
        }

        public enum ServiceBootFlag
        {
            Start = 0x00000000,
            SystemStart = 0x00000001,
            AutoStart = 0x00000002,
            DemandStart = 0x00000003,
            Disabled = 0x00000004
        }

        public enum ServiceState
        {
            Unknown = -1, // The state cannot be (has not been) retrieved.
            NotFound = 0, // The service is not known on the host server.
            Stop = 1, // The service is NET stopped.
            Run = 2, // The service is NET started.
            Stopping = 3,
            Starting = 4,
        }

        public enum ServiceControl
        {
            Stop = 0x00000001,
            Pause = 0x00000002,
            Continue = 0x00000003,
            Interrogate = 0x00000004,
            Shutdown = 0x00000005,
            ParamChange = 0x00000006,
            NetBindAdd = 0x00000007,
            NetBindRemove = 0x00000008,
            NetBindEnable = 0x00000009,
            NetBindDisable = 0x0000000A
        }

        public enum ServiceError
        {
            Ignore = 0x00000000,
            Normal = 0x00000001,
            Severe = 0x00000002,
            Critical = 0x00000003
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class SERVICE_STATUS
        {
            public int dwServiceType = 0;
            public ServiceState dwCurrentState = 0;
            public int dwControlsAccepted = 0;
            public int dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
            public int dwCheckPoint = 0;
            public int dwWaitHint = 0;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerA")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, ServiceManagerRights dwDesiredAccess);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenServiceA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, ServiceRights dwDesiredAccess);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateServiceA")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceRights dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DeleteService(IntPtr hService);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int ControlService(IntPtr hService, ServiceControl dwControl, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "StartServiceA")]
        private static extern int StartService(IntPtr hService, int dwNumServiceArgs, int lpServiceArgVectors);

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a service name and tries to stop and then uninstall the windows serviceError
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName">The windows service name to uninstall</param>
        public static void Uninstall(string ServiceName)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scman, ServiceName, ServiceRights.StandardRightsRequired | ServiceRights.Stop | ServiceRights.QueryStatus);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Service not installed.");
                }
                try
                {
                    StopService(service);
                    int ret = DeleteService(service);
                    if (ret == 0)
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new ApplicationException("Could not delete service " + error);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Accepts a service name and returns true if the service with that service name exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName">The service name that we will check for existence</param>
        /// <returns>True if that service exists false otherwise</returns>
        public static bool ServiceIsInstalled(string ServiceName)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scman, ServiceName,
                ServiceRights.QueryStatus);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                CloseServiceHandle(service);
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a service name, a service display name and the path to the service executable and installs / starts the windows service.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName">The service name that this service will have</param>
        /// <param name="DisplayName">The display name that this service will have</param>
        /// <param name="FileName">The path to the executable of the service</param>
        public static void InstallAndStart(string ServiceName, string DisplayName,
        string FileName)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect |
            ServiceManagerRights.CreateService);
            try
            {
                string strKey = string.Empty;
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scman, ServiceName,
                ServiceRights.QueryStatus | ServiceRights.Start);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    service = CreateService(scman, ServiceName, DisplayName,
                    ServiceRights.QueryStatus | ServiceRights.Start, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                    ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, ServiceError.Normal, FileName, null, IntPtr.Zero,
                    null, null, null);
                    ServiceLogs(ServiceName + " Installed Sucessfully.!", strPath);
                    Console.Write(ServiceName + " Installed Sucessfully.! Do you want to Start the Service.Y/N.?");
                    strKey=Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    ServiceLogs("Failed to install service.", strPath);
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");
                }
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strKey) && (strKey.StartsWith("y") || strKey.StartsWith("Y")))
                    {
                        StartService(service);
                        ServiceLogs(ServiceName + " Started Sucessfully.!", strPath);
                        Console.Write(ServiceName + " Started Sucessfully.!");
                        Console.Read();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a service name and starts it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Name">The service name</param>
        public static void StartService(string Name)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
            try
            {
                IntPtr hService = OpenService(scman, Name, ServiceRights.QueryStatus |
                ServiceRights.Start);
                if (hService == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    ServiceLogs("Could not open service.", strPath);
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");
                }
                try
                {
                    StartService(hService);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the provided windows service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Name">The service name that will be stopped</param>
        public static void StopService(string Name)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
            try
            {
                IntPtr hService = OpenService(scman, Name, ServiceRights.QueryStatus |
                ServiceRights.Stop);
                if (hService == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    ServiceLogs("Could not open service.", strPath);
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");
                }
                try
                {
                    StopService(hService);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
                }



}
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stars the provided windows service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hService">The handle to the windows service</param>
        private static void StartService(IntPtr hService)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            StartService(hService, 0, 0);
            WaitForServiceStatus(hService, ServiceState.Starting, ServiceState.Run);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the provided windows service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hService">The handle to the windows service</param>
        private static void StopService(IntPtr hService)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            ControlService(hService, ServiceControl.Stop, status);
            WaitForServiceStatus(hService, ServiceState.Stopping, ServiceState.Stop);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a service name and returns the <code>ServiceState</code> of the corresponding service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ServiceName">The service name that we will check for his <code>ServiceState</code></param>
        /// <returns>The ServiceState of the service we wanted to check</returns>
        public static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(string ServiceName)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights.Connect);
            try
            {
                IntPtr hService = OpenService(scman, ServiceName,
                ServiceRights.QueryStatus);
                if (hService == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return ServiceState.NotFound;
                }
                try
                {
                    return GetServiceStatus(hService);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(scman);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scman);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the service state by using the handle of the provided windows service
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hService">The handle to the service</param>
        /// <returns>The <code>ServiceState</code> of the service</returns>
        private static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(IntPtr hService)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS ssStatus = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            if (QueryServiceStatus(hService, ssStatus) == 0)
            {
                ServiceLogs("Failed to query service status.", strPath);
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to query service status.");
            }
            return ssStatus.dwCurrentState;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true when the service status has been changes from wait status to desired status
        /// ,this method waits around 10 seconds for this operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hService">The handle to the service</param>
        /// <param name="WaitStatus">The current state of the service</param>
        /// <param name="DesiredStatus">The desired state of the service</param>
        /// <returns>bool if the service has successfully changed states within the allowed timeline</returns>
        private static bool WaitForServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, ServiceState
        WaitStatus, ServiceState DesiredStatus)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS ssStatus = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            int dwOldCheckPoint;
            int dwStartTickCount;

            QueryServiceStatus(hService, ssStatus);
            if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == DesiredStatus) return true;
            dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

            while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == WaitStatus)
            {
                // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
                // one tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no
                // more than 10 seconds.

                int dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

                if (dwWaitTime < 1000) dwWaitTime = 1000;
                else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) dwWaitTime = 10000;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(dwWaitTime);

                // Check the status again.

                if (QueryServiceStatus(hService, ssStatus) == 0) break;

                if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
                {
                    // The service is making progress.
                    dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
                    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Environment.TickCount - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
                    {
                        // No progress made within the wait hint
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == DesiredStatus);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens the service manager
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Rights">The service manager rights</param>
        /// <returns>the handle to the service manager</returns>
        private static IntPtr OpenSCManager(ServiceManagerRights Rights)
        {
            IntPtr scman = OpenSCManager(null, null, Rights);
            if (scman == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to service control manager.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            return scman;
        }

        #endregion

        #region"CreateFolderStructure"
        private static void CreateFolderStructure(string path)
        {
            if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path+"Applications"))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path+ "Applications");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path + "Applications\\MSC"))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "Applications\\MSC");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path + "Applications\\MSC\\Agent"))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "Applications\\MSC\\Agent");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path + "Applications\\MSC\\Agent\\bin"))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "Applications\\MSC\\Agent\\bin");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path + "Applications\\MSC\\AgentService"))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "Applications\\MSC\\AgentService");

            string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("MSCService");
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                foreach (string strFile in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullPath))
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFile))
                    {
                        String[] strArr = strFile.Split('\\');
                        System.IO.File.Copy(strFile, path + "Applications\\MSC\\Agent\\bin\\"+ strArr[strArr.Count()-1], true);
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
        #endregion

        private static void ServiceLogs(string strLogInfo, string path)
        {
            string filePath = path + "Applications\\MSC\\AgentService\\ServiceLogs.txt";            
            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(filePath, (strLogInfo + "--" + DateTime.Now.ToString()).ToString().Split('|'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to add useful commentary with your code to describe what it is doing and how it solves the problem rather than just posting the code itself.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

As pierre said, there is no way to have a user interface for a windows service (or no easy way). What I do in that kind of situation is to have a settings file that is read from the service on whatever interval the service operates on and have a standalone application that makes changes to the settings file.

Comment: Please read my comments to other answers, I don`t need a ui for service.

Answer (score 0):

Does your console app require user interaction?  If so, that's a serious no-no and you should redesign your application.  While there are some hacks to make this sort of work in older versions of the OS, this is guaranteed to break in the future.

If your app does not require user interaction, then perhaps your problem is related to the user the service is running as.  Try making sure that you run as the correct user, or that the user and/or resources you are using have the right permissions.

If you require some kind of user-interaction, then you will need to create a client application and communicate with the service and/or sub-application via rpc, sockets, or named pipes.

Comment: No interaction needed. I tried system account and my admin account. I think admin account should be enuogh to launch a console app.

Answer (score 0):

Services are required to connect to the Service Control Manager and provide feedback at start up (ie. tell SCM 'I'm alive!'). That's why C# application have a different project template for services. You have two alternatives:

- wrapp your exe on srvany.exe, as described in KB [How To Create a User-Defined Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)
- have your C# app detect when is launched as a service (eg. command line param) and switch control to a class that inherits from [ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28VS.80%29.aspx) and properly implements a service.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows service, and I added the following line to the constructor for my service:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
try {
    Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe");
} catch {
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

When I tried to run this, the Process.Start() call was made, and no exception occurred.  However, the calc.exe application did not show up.  In order to make it work, I had edit the properties for my service in the Service Control Manager to enable interaction with the desktop.  After doing that, the Process.Start() opened calc.exe as expected.

But as others have said, interaction with the desktop is frowned upon by Microsoft and has essentially been disabled in Vista.  So even if you can get it to work in XP, I don't know that you'll be able to make it work in Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I use this class:

```
class ProcessWrapper : Process, IDisposable
{
    public enum PipeType { StdOut, StdErr }

    public class Output
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public PipeType Pipe { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Pipe}: {Message}";
        }
    }

    private readonly string _command;
    private readonly string _args;
    private readonly bool _showWindow;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    private readonly Queue<Output> _outputQueue = new Queue<Output>();

    private readonly ManualResetEvent[] _waitHandles = new ManualResetEvent[2];
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _outputSteamWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public ProcessWrapper(string startCommand, string args, bool showWindow = false)
    {
        _command = startCommand;
        _args = args;
        _showWindow = showWindow;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetMessages()
    {
        while (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _outputSteamWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            if (_outputQueue.Any())
                yield return _outputQueue.Dequeue().ToString();
        }
    }

    public void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        StandardInput.Write(command);
        StandardInput.Flush();
    }

    public new int Start()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = _command,
            Arguments = _args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = !_showWindow
        };
        StartInfo = startInfo;

        OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Data == null)
            {
                _waitHandles[0].Set();
            }
            else if (args.Data.Length > 0)
            {
                _outputQueue.Enqueue(new Output { Message = args.Data, Pipe = PipeType.StdOut });
                _outputSteamWaitHandle.Set();
            }
        };

        ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Data == null)
            {
                _waitHandles[1].Set();
            }
            else if (args.Data.Length > 0)
            {
                _outputSteamWaitHandle.Set();
                _outputQueue.Enqueue(new Output { Message = args.Data, Pipe = PipeType.StdErr });
            }
        };

        base.Start();

        _waitHandles[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        BeginErrorReadLine();
        _waitHandles[1] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        BeginOutputReadLine();

        return Id;
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        StandardInput.Flush();
        StandardInput.Close();
        if (!WaitForExit(1000))
        {
            Kill();
        }
        if (WaitForExit(1000))
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(_waitHandles);
        }
        base.Dispose();
        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -12):

Running in Windows Services any application like for example ".exe" is weird to do because the algorithm is not that effective.

Comment: Why? We have applications published both as console apps ans services. A console app is much easier to debug for instance.

Comment: Writing senseless statements is even less effective

Comment: How would that affect the algorithm effectiveness?