# calling different type of job using scheduler developed in c# and window service

Tags: inheritance, service, scheduler

I have developed one window service which is working as scheduler. This scheduler is capable of triggering event based on criteria set in the database. Currently it is only capable of starting and stopping another window service. I want to change the code such that it can do many task and that code should be extended so existing code will not be changed.

Please give me your ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share what kind of tasks you want to do. Since you want to perform many tasks without changing the codebase, one approach can be to launch separate exe's for separate tasks which take command line arguments supplied from database.

Comment: i want to call store procedure, call scripts, starting or stopping window service. one more category is to call some customised object which perform some task but that is currently incorporated in different window services. it also can be incorporated to exe or dll in a way.

Comment: Better create separate exe's for separate action and call them through your service.

Comment: Thanks Deepansh Gupta. But i want to make generic code which call these exe and will not be changed when new exe is added.                           please tell me if you have any idea or sample code for the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369236/how-to-run-console-application-from-windows-service This link is worth a look.