# I need to pass a command line script to a program from a windows service

Tags: c#, service, command-line, permissions, windows-services

Right now, I currently have this working, but it's a workaround, which won't be optimal in the future.
I'm currently writing a service which will have to pass some command line arguments to a program, which will then handle some things behind the scenes that I don't need to worry about.
The problem i'm having is: Right now when I install my service, I need to go into the service's properties, and log in to it as my user. If I use the Local System (with interact with desktop checked), It doesn't work. (It actually doesn't fail either, which is strange, but aside the point). 
I'm wondering if there is a General user I can programatically log in to (Like Network Service), which will get this to work. Or is it maybe a permissions issue?

Comment: do you have a control over the other app, the one with command line?

Comment: no it's handled by another development team; i only have control over the one that passes the command line arguments

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369236/how-to-run-console-application-from-windows-service

Comment: In a way yes it is, but there isn't a working answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start external program from windows service, you need to use WinAPI function CreateProcessAsUser. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715894/why-wont-my-windows-service-install-another-program-from-a-process/16722367#16722367).