# How to call buggy .dll in new process?

Tags: c#, dll, service, process, background

I have a c# windows service application that is crashing without throwing an exception when processing certain files using a third-party .dll.  What I decided to do was create a new console application which replicates a small portion of the windows service code, particularly the part the causes the service to crash.  What I want to do is call the new .exe program from the windows service, and if it crashes, I throw an exception myself.

So, I need to call this .exe program (not in the background as I can't allow the windows service to continue until I know the file to be processed is safe), and then determine if it exited successfully or not.  How do I go about doing this?  The examples I've seen run the .exe in a background process which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369252/351383) how to run console application from windows service. Just add WaitForExit, like this :

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\myprogram.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.ErrorDialog = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process process = Process.Start(info);
process.WaitForExit();
```

In console application you can set exit code if you exit with `Environment.Exit(statusCode)` or return int value from main function of console applicaiton. Or you can write to output and then in your service examine exit code (`process.ExitCode`) or output stream so you can determine is process was exited successfully.

Comment: Thanks :)  Can't believe I didn't notice WaitForExit() in the Process api docs.