# Why is my Windows C# Service Crashing?

Tags: c#, windows, service, process

I am writing a Windows Service that among other things needs to start a secondary program with Administrative rights. The service works perfect except when trying to load the secondary program. Following is the code. "Update Found" is echoed to the log however the strange part is that "Exception" or the exception.tostring() is not. The service can be started, ran and stopped without this new code pasted below. Now that I am trying to launch another program from the service, the service quickly echoes "Update Found" and I notice the service reads "Service Stopped" in services.msc immediately after.

Does anyone see why my Windows C# Service is crashing when starting the second program?

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt", "Update Found\r\n");
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process processss = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfooo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfooo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfooo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfooo.Arguments = "/C " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Manager.exe";
    processss.StartInfo = startInfooo;
    processss.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt", "Exception");
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt",ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows Vista or later, due to service isolation you won't be able to start any interactive applications.

Here are some good answers for your question:

[How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c)

[How to run console application from Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369236/how-to-run-console-application-from-windows-service)