# Starting a console application from a Windows Service/Can it be done/How can it be done?

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application

I'm working on a project and need guidance and examples(if possible). I have a console application that does not interact with the user. The console app reads an excel file and prints a value to a run-time created text file. I would like the console app to run when files in a directory are created or updated.
My plan:
My plan is to create a Windows Service that uses the FileSystemWatcher class to watch a directory and run the console app exe when the filesystemwatcher is notified of a change.
Anyone have helpful links, advice, or examples I can use to complete the project.
thanks!

Comment: you can simply create a new process and run the console app. just like you do it in a WinForms, or console app

Answer (score 0):

By default a windows service cannot interact with the UI, so you cannot start a visible console window. Since Vista there is an option to allow interaction with the UI (see "Allow Service to interact with desktop").

However, I think this question has already been answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369236/how-to-run-console-application-from-windows-service).

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing to me.. You can have a visible console window/app doing work without interacting with it. It'll just do its work and close when finished (unless you have code telling it to hold open/wait for input of some kind of course). I'm not sure what UI you think this service would need to be interacting with.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: If I remember right you cannot start a visible console window by default, because it's still UI, even if it won't require any input. If you need a visible window, you will probably need to allow service to interact with desktop or have an application running which communicates with the service via named pipes or something.
But I think that's a little bit off-topic as I don't think that the thread starter needs a visible window. I just wanted to mention it, just in case..