# Python as Windows Service Using speedtest-cli returns Error 1053

Tags: python, windows

I have successfully created a py script that monitors network bandwidth and records it in a database. When I run it in debug everything works perfectly. However, when I start the service it errors with a 1053. If I comment out the `import speedtest` the windows service starts just fine. I know the issue is directly related to the module.

I searched the web to it's furthest reaches trying to figure this one out. I have increased my windows service timeout and made sure that my cx_freeze includes the speedtest module, among other small adjustments for testing purposes. All of which still result in the same error on windows service start.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As I understand it, the `speedtest` module does what it does by starting up a subprocess and running a command line program. Windows does not allow services to interact with the console. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369236/how-to-run-console-application-from-windows-service might help, and then again it might not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I'm going to have to find an alternate solution.