# C# - Is it possible to create a Windows Forms application that can run from the command line with parameters?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line

I would like a Windows Forms application that will contain a UI, but I want it to run from the command line with some parameters, possibly also a `/hide` or `/visible=false` option.

How is it possible to read in the command line parameters? And adjust accordingly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you change this default Main signature:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
```

To this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(String[] args)
```

You can access the commandline variables as you would from a normal console app, or if you want to access them from elsewhere you can use:

```
System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: Hah, that first method is what I used in an explanation to a friend a while back. +1

Answer (score 8):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        // Run the application in a windows form
        Application.Run(new MainForm( ));
    }
    else
    {
        // Run app from CLI
        Console.WriteLine(DoStuff(args));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the second part of the question.  You are missing a bracket at the end of WriteLine(.  Also, I don't think you can write to the console like that in a windows form application.

Comment: You are right that you cannot Console.WriteLine to a Winforms app. The point of my answer is that you need not create a Windforms app, you can create a single executable that will run as a form or command-line depending on how it is invoked.

Comment: I just tested this and there is no commandwindow open for the text, I think it's missing a command to startup the comamndline window.

Comment: @Eric, good catch; an example that connects to StdOut is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1040730/22437). `Console.WriteLine` was probably a bad example for such a short snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work to create the project as a normal windows app project.  Then in program.cs before you launch the window, call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to get the command line arguments and parse them to do what you want.